# javascript object property value conflict

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I'm not very sure about the question title,
here is the situation, please see the following sample code

```
// original data
a = [
  {x : 1},
  {x : 2},
  {x : 3}
]

// assign to a variable  
b = a[0]

// do some change
b.x = 5

alert(a[0].x) 
// i thought it would still be 1 but it is 5, why???
```

*edit 
thank you Amber and Andrei 
i think i'll just write a function to loop through object properties to copy to a new object
thanks for the help again :)

Comment: You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object for some suggestions on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are assigned by reference - which means that when you modify anything that references the object, it modifies it in every case where it's referenced.

`b` is merely storing a reference to the same object that `a[0]` is storing a reference to.

Comment: is there any way to avoid this happened?
or every time i want to modify an object property i have to store it to another variable?

Comment: so what if i need to copy the data stored in a to another obj without reference to a?

Comment: You have to do what's called a 'deep copy' - http://snipplr.com/view/15407/deep-copy-an-array-or-object/

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way. `a[0]` is not the actual object `{x : 1}`. That object is somewhere in memory, and `a[0]` holds the memory address where that object is stored.

If you do `a[0].x` you dereference it. That means that you analyze the part before the `.` and see the address. You then fetch the object at that address and see if it has a property `x` and return it.

But if you do `b=a[0]` you're basically just copying the address of the object into b. So now you have two references (shortcuts to the memory address were the object is stored). If you now do `b.x = 5` you look at what's before the `.`; it's `b` containing the address of the object, you fetch that object from memory, check if it has property `x` and change its value to 5. But `a[0]` points at the same address (so at the same object) so if you try to do `a[0].x` like before, you arrive at the address you just modified.

This is a bit of a simplified explanation, but you should think of variables holding objects as shortcuts to the memory address where the actual object is. And if you try to assign a variable the value of another object variable, your just making a new shortcut. This isn't true for variables holding numbers, so x actually holds the value `1`, or `5`, not an address. So if you do:

```
y = a[0].x;
y = 10;
```

`a[0].x` will not change its value .

Comment: thanks Andrei :) i guess this means i can't just copy a while tree of a object node to another object, i'll have to assign values one by one :(